# tomcat starts but show Error can't reach this page

Tags: eclipse, apache

I am using **Eclipse Oxygen** and in that, I have configured **Apache Tomcat v8.5.4** I am running a simple **spring MVC** program, when I attempt to run the program as
Run As->Run on Server Apache starts and after a moment I can see this

[image]

what can be the cause of it and how to resolve it..??

Note: I have changed the port for localhost to 8081

see this is the complete error notice

```
Aug 10, 2017 3:15:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
WARNING: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library failed to load. The error reported was [C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.4\bin\tcnative-1.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform]
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.4\bin\tcnative-1.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jni.Library.<init>(Library.java:42)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jni.Library.initialize(Library.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.init(AprLifecycleListener.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.isAprAvailable(AprLifecycleListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.setProtocol(Connector.java:587)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.<init>(Connector.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ConnectorCreateRule.begin(ConnectorCreateRule.java:64)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1188)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1461)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:578)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:629)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:494)

Aug 10, 2017 3:15:29 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:MVC_HelloWorld' did not find a matching property.
Aug 10, 2017 3:15:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.4
Aug 10, 2017 3:15:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Jul 6 2016 08:43:30 UTC
Aug 10, 2017 3:15:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         8.5.4.0
Aug 10, 2017 3:15:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 10
Aug 10, 2017 3:15:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.0
Aug 10, 2017 3:15:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Aug 10, 2017 3:15:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144
Aug 10, 2017 3:15:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_144-b01
Aug 10, 2017 3:15:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Aug 10, 2017 3:15:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.4
Aug 10, 2017 3:15:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.4
Aug 10, 2017 3:15:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.4
Aug 10, 2017 3:15:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.4
Aug 10, 2017 3:15:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.4\wtpwebapps
Aug 10, 2017 3:15:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.4\endorsed
Aug 10, 2017 3:15:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Aug 10, 2017 3:15:35 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8082"]
Aug 10, 2017 3:15:37 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Aug 10, 2017 3:15:37 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Aug 10, 2017 3:15:37 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Aug 10, 2017 3:15:37 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 19471 ms
Aug 10, 2017 3:15:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Aug 10, 2017 3:15:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.4
Aug 10, 2017 3:15:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/MVC_HelloWorld]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:911)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:890)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1403)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/MVC_HelloWorld]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:158)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Servlet mapping specifies an unknown servlet name HelloWorld
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3124)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3103)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureContext(ContextConfig.java:1367)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1181)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:298)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5076)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    ... 6 more

Aug 10, 2017 3:15:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:911)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:655)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1403)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:890)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    ... 6 more

Aug 10, 2017 3:15:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:655)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    ... 11 more

Aug 10, 2017 3:15:42 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8082"]
Aug 10, 2017 3:15:42 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Aug 10, 2017 3:15:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Aug 10, 2017 3:15:42 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8082"]
Aug 10, 2017 3:15:42 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
```

Comment: Is the server running? (In the snapshot it says "stopped").

Comment: when I run the project then it says "started, synchronized" after a moment it says "stopped"

Comment: Ah, ah. That is the cause. Review the output console tab to find out why it didn't get to start successfully. Check if there have been any errors during startup.

Comment: I can see this into the console tab  >SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/MVC_HelloWorld]]

Comment: Too short as an error description... I recommend you too read the whole console output, in case there were other previous error traces which willl provide more information. And also, as a test, you could create another new server, with a new port addresss, and start it. If it does not start, something is wrong with the Tomcat's installation. If it gets started, then stop it and add your project into that server, and re-start it.